# VB.net DataGridView not display the Data from MySql Data base

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to display the data from `MySql database` using `DataGridView` `DataSource` and `MySqlDataAdapter` filling a `DataTable` .
Then the data goes into the `DataGridView`. I do not know what is the problem, everything seems right and my code is correct, but nothing is being displayed on my `DataGridView`.

```
 Try
            Me.DataGridViewp.DataSource = Nothing

            ConnDB()
            sqL = "SELECT picture FROM product"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqL, conn)
            Dim dtSample As New DataTable
            Dim daSample As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            daSample.Fill(dtSample)

            Me.DataGridViewp.DataSource = dtSample

            conn.Close()
            conn.Dispose()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure `dtSample` actually contains rows and columns?

Comment: What is the MySql datatype for the picture field?

Comment: picture is blob image field storing images

Comment: it is giving an Exception message "the given key was not present in the dictionary" ..... ?

Comment: You should always add the error you are getting to the question. In addition, I do not see anywhere in the posted code that would throw the error _"the given key was not present in the dictionary"_ … this error appears to be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Edit your question and add the error message to it. Also specify what line of code the exception is thrown on. ALWAYS provide ALL the relevant information in the question in the first place and the symptoms of the issue are ALWAYS relevant. If you discover further information is relevant later, ALWAYS update the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to show an image in a DatGridView. You should see your images if they are available in the database as byte array. otherwise, it will not be shown in the DatGridView.

I use the following function to convert images to byte array before saving it to the database. Following is a sample code to convert it to byte array before saving. (I am attaching the code as an image since it does not show correctly formatted when I paste it here). You have to add a reference (System.IO) for this code to work in your relevant form.

This works for me and hope this helps you.

[image].

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Enter the text as part of the answer and format as code.